# set useragent in scrapy file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Im looking to set my `useragent` to different values per request.

I currently has code that finds links on a webpage:

```
    wee_result_page = []
    start_urls = ['oneurl.com']

    NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = 'a.sb_pagN ::attr(href)'
    next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(next_page),
            callback=self.parse,
            headers={'referer':start_urls}
        )
        wee_result_page.append(response.urljoin(next_page))
```

Im wonder where and how I can add a `user agent` string here, that changes on each request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it per request as header or create custom downloader middleware that appends random user-agent to each request, however there are number of user-agent rotating middlewares available, that will do the job for you, for ex.) https://github.com/cnu/scrapy-random-useragent

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how do I create the `settings` file to use any of these middlewares?